# Why are the crew members in Passengers locked in?

Tags: plot-explanation, passengers

Why was the whole crew of the ship in *Passengers* locked in a separated room which no regular passenger had access to?

What reason could there be to separate them from the passengers? They even said that a system malfunction is impossible and if I remember that correctly someone also mentioned that the crew will awake before them.

So why are these crew members all locked into their own part of the ship?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's standard security practice to separate critical systems in case of fire, terrorism,  or asset protection. A malfunction of the sleep pods may be unlikely, but intentional attacks are not. It parallels modern day practices of locking the cockpit.

In Passengers, it's explicitly called a fire wall.